# JWT laravel: check auth. Cannot check if user is authenticated even i have set the token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm trying make a mobile application with vue and i'm using jwt in laravel. 
On first login, I can access the `auth()->check()` then I get false after the app is cancelled. I'm saving the `token`. I'm saving the token in local storage. How can I get the authenticated user.

**controller:**

```
 public function JwtAuth(){ 
        if($this->getAuthenticatedUser()){
            return $this->JwtUser = $this->getAuthenticatedUser();
        }
        return [];       
    }
```

I want to acheive something like:

```
if(auth()->user()){
    $user = "something";
}else{
     $user = '';
}
return $user;
```

So sometime I will have token and sometime i dont .. how to check?

Comment: `auth()->user()` returns `null` if there is no authenticated user and returns the user if there is an authenticated user. So the condition `if (auth()->user()) { // }` should work fine...

Comment: No its not working..... after I reload the page my session ends... i'm just left with token...